# Kubernetes Job error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a kubernetes job to fetch the annotation from a deployment however when the job is executed I see the error as below in the logs of that particular job:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

However,  when I manually execute the command in my VM it works fine. I did check the permissions of service account and I do have access to read the deployments.

1. `Role.yaml`:

```yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: deployment-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

2. `RoleBinding.yaml`:

```yaml
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-deployments
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: deployment-reader
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: deployment-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

3. `ServiceAccount.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deployment-reader
  namespace: default
```

4. `Job.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: get-annotation-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: deployment-reader
      containers:
      - name: get-annotation
        image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["kubectl get deployment test-deployment -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.test_checksum}' > /output/annotation.txt"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: output
          mountPath: /output
      volumes:
      - name: output
        emptyDir: {}
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Also, I am using kubernetes in docker.

Comment: I guess, it works on vm cause kubectl has correct config file, (which is usually under `~.kube/config`). But in the `get-annotation` container, the kubectl does not have access to the vm's  kube `config` file. So, I would like to suggest to make a volume for the container and map the kubeconfig file to the container. Hope it helps

Comment: I have another job that actually annotates this deployment with almost same configuration but with patch role to annotate and it works just fine, not sure whats wrong with this job